# How to set an int @Required in a Form in Play Framework?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

I have a class that is passed to `form()`:

```
public static class Creation {
        @Required(message = "Checkpoint name is required")
        public String name;

        @Required(message = "Longitude degrees are required")
        public double longitudeDegrees;

        @Required(message = "Longitude minutes are required")
        public double longitudeMinutes;

        @Required(message = "Latitude degrees are required")
        public double latitudeDegrees;

        @Required(message = "Latitude minutes are required")
        public double latitudeMinutes;

        @Required(message = "Message is required")
        public String message;

        @Required(message = "Points are required")  
        @Min(value= 1, message = "Points min. = 0")
        public int points;
}
```

When I submit my form with the points field empty, I get `error.invalid` in the form errors. If I put "0", I get the "Points min. = 0" error. What should I do to get the "Points are required" message, when the field is empty?

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer. Change field types `int` and `double` into `Integer` and `Double`.